# python 3 как отследить нажатие на кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Как мне отследить нажатие на кнопку клавиатуры если python скрипт запущен в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отследить нажатие кнопок можно через модуль `keyboard`:

```
pip install keyboard
```

- Это пример для отслеживания клика по горячим кнопкам:

  ```
  import keyboard

  def foo():
      print('World')

  keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', lambda: print('Hello'))
  keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 2', foo)

  keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
  ```
- Отслеживание всех кликов на кнопки:

  ```
  import keyboard

  def print_pressed_keys(e):
      print(e, e.event_type, e.name)

  keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
  keyboard.wait()
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Вот таким способом решил эту задачу я:

```py
import keyboard

translate = {
    'down':' нажал на клавишу ',
    'up':' отпустил клавишу '
}


def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(
        'Пользователь {}{}'.format(translate[e.event_type], e.name)
        )


keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Как видишь, я использовал модуль keyboard.
Подробнее ознакомиться с ним можно [здесь](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

Answer (score 3):

Установка:

```
pip install pynput
```

Вот таким способом:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```