# Как заставить работать input() без пауз?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В вопросе, думаю, все понятно.

```
amps = 0
tsu = 1000
ad1 = 10
ad2 = 100
ad3 = 10 ^ 4
ad4 = 10 ^ 6
ad5 = 10 ^ 9
ad6 = 10 ^ 12
ad7 = 10 ^ 18
ad8 = 10 ^ 24

while True:
    print("\n" * 25)
    print("У вас ", am, " антиматерии")
    print("Купить ускорение: ", tsu, " антиматерии (b)")
    print("Купить 1 измерение антиматерии: ", ad1, "антиматерии (1)")
    print("Купить 2 измерение антиматерии: ", ad2, "антиматерии (2)")
    print("Купить 3 измерение антиматерии: ", ad3, "антиматерии (3)")
    print("Купить 4 измерение антиматерии: ", ad4, "антиматерии (4)")
    print("Купить 5 измерение антиматерии: ", ad5, "антиматерии (5)")
    print("Купить 6 измерение антиматерии: ", ad6, "антиматерии (6)")
    print("Купить 7 измерение антиматерии: ", ad7, "антиматерии (7)")
    print("Купить 8 измерение антиматерии: ", ad8, "антиматерии (8)")
    sel = input("Напишите символ в скобочках, чтобы выбрать действие: ")
```

Comment: Без каких пауз? Не считая того, что код в принципе не работает, так как в первом принте у вас `am` вместо `amps`, пауза появляется только для инпута.

Comment: Не ждать ввода "символа перевода строки" (нажатия Enter) что-ли?

Comment: Когда input() срабатывает, то цикл останавливается, пока человек не напишет что-то и не нажмет Enter

Comment: А как по-вашему человек должен что-то вводить, если для этого не будет паузы? Или вы хотите сделать как бы прерывание, как будто человек реально нажимает на соответствующую кнопку "купить"?

Comment: @EzikBro, можно сделать так, как ты написал, но изначально я хотел чтобы человек писал, пока код работает отдельно (без паузы)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python 3 как отследить нажатие на кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841014/python-3-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @GrAnd, сейчас попробую